# How to read & update xml file in android?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

It may be a basic question but I am new to xml parsing, that's why I need some help. So the question is: I just want to read a xml file from res folder in android and update the values for some tag in that file; so, howcan it be done? Please help me out. Following is the xml file and I want to update the value of the tag "event filter" which is currently having value "moneyback". I had searched many threads but still I am unable to solve the issue.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <HawkAgentPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <config>
  <installedappthreadtime>10</installedappthreadtime>
  <runningprocessthreadtime>10</runningprocessthreadtime>
  <networkconnectionsthreadtime>10</networkconnectionsthreadtime>
</config>
<policy name="DayCapturePolicy" type="capture">
 <starttime>9:00:00 AM</starttime>
 <endtime>9:00:00 PM</endtime>
 <event name="NEW_APP_INSTALLED">
  <eventFilter selectedAppName="Moneyback"/> 
   <eventParam>selectedAppName</eventParam>
  <eventParam>selectedAppVersion</eventParam>
  <eventParam>appPackageName</eventParam>
  <eventParam>appDirPath</eventParam>
</event>
<event name="NEW_PROCESS_STARTED">
  <eventFilter runningAppName="Moneyback" /> 
  <eventParam>runningAppName</eventParam>
  <eventParam>runningAppProcessId</eventParam>
  <eventParam>runningProcessName</eventParam>
</event>
<event name="INBOUND_CONNECTION">    
  <eventFilter netAppName="Moneyback"/> 
  <eventParam>netProtocol</eventParam>
  <eventParam>netRemoteIP</eventParam>
  <eventParam>netRemotePort</eventParam>
  <eventParam>netStatus</eventParam>
  <eventParam>netUID</eventParam>
  <eventParam>netAppName</eventParam>
</event>
<event name="OUTBOUND_CONNECTION">
<eventFilter netAppName="Moneyback"/> 
<eventParam>netProtocol</eventParam>
  <eventParam>netRemoteIP</eventParam>
  <eventParam>netRemotePort</eventParam>
  <eventParam>netStatus</eventParam>
  <eventParam>netUID</eventParam>
  <eventParam>netAppName</eventParam>
 </event>
 </policy>
</HawkAgentPolicy>
```

Comment: you can read file, but not write to it. they are read only

Comment: there are some threads available on internet for updating xml but i am unable to apply it for my xml thats why i post the above question

Comment: if xml is on filesystem, you could change it, but if it is in res folder of apk, then you cannot, it is packaged with the apk

Comment: i want to update the content of xml any ways so please provide me any feasible solution should i keep my file in assets folder?